# Firefox: Is there any way I can backup all extensions and extension data and import it into other profiles, or import it back after refreshing FF?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

Within the past few days, I've noticed Firefox act buggy and then got the message “The bookmarks and history system will not be functional … ” so I deleted my profile like it said so [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-bookmarks-and-history-will-not-be-functional). I had backed up all my extension settings beforehand, but it would be more convenient to backup and import them all at once with one or a few clicks.

Comment: Unless you are storing passwords, which is encrypted by the the Windows user's password, you should be able to just copy and paste the Firefox user profile on another machine. I routinely perform that operation.  You can also synchronize your profile into the cloud I suppose,although that won't necessarly, syncrhonize extension data.

Comment: Well I'm wonder if there are solutions other than copy and pasting profiles to backup extensions.